# Do I need to close the stream from FileReader() in Android&?

Tags: java, android, stream

can anyone explain why the author does not close the stream LineNumberReader lnr? Is this not necessary?

```
protected static ArrayList<Mount> getMounts() throws Exception{
    LineNumberReader lnr = null;
    lnr = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader("/proc/mounts"));
    String line;
    ArrayList<Mount> mounts = new ArrayList<Mount>();
    while ((line = lnr.readLine()) != null)
    {  
        RootTools.log(line);

        String[] fields = line.split(" ");
        mounts.add(new Mount(new File(fields[0]), // device
            new File(fields[1]), // mountPoint
            fields[2], // fstype
            fields[3] // flags
        ));
    }
    InternalVariables.mounts = mounts;

    if (InternalVariables.mounts != null) {
        return InternalVariables.mounts;
    } else {
        throw new Exception();
    }
}
```

Moreover, in previous versions was:

```
finally {
    //no need to do anything here.
}
```

[source code](http://code.google.com/p/roottools/source/browse/trunk/Stable/RootTools-sdk3-generic/src/com/stericson/RootTools/InternalMethods.java)

Is this a mistake or specifics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's technically not necessary since the object will be deleted by the GC when it goes out of scope, and the teardown process could close it. It's considered a good practice to close any I/O streams you open, just to make sure.